# How to implement tracing in eventbus in vertx using opentracing or opentelemetry?

Tags: vert.x, distributed-tracing, vertx-eventbus

The webpage doesn't give much description on the same, Share some examples if possible.

```java
    public class MainVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
        
        Tracer tracer=GlobalTracer.getTracer();
        @Override
        public void start() {
            vertx.deployVerticle(new MainVerticle());
            Router router =Router.router(vertx);
            router.get("/home").handler(this::message);
            router.get("/home/:name").handler(this::messagectm);
            Tracer tracer = getTracer();
            vertx.createHttpServer(new HttpServerOptions().setTracingPolicy(TracingPolicy.ALWAYS)).requestHandler(router).listen(8080);
            Span span = tracer.buildSpan("my-operation")
          .withTag("example", "test")
          .start();
          OpenTracingUtil.setSpan(span);
          DeliveryOptions options = new DeliveryOptions().setTracingPolicy(TracingPolicy.ALWAYS);
            vertx.eventBus().send("addr","test",options);
            span.finish();
        }
```

This is my sample implementation that I tried but didn't work as expected

Comment: Please add some more description to your problem statement. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`start()` method is basically what happens during bootstrap. What you're actually doing is creating a span only once, when the application starts, and immediately close it.

What you actually want to do is open a span in each route, similar to this:

```java
router.get("/home").handler((ctx) -> {
    Span span = tracer.buildSpan("my-operation")
      .withTag("example", "test")
      .start();
    this.message(ctx);
    span.finish();
});
```

Now, this code above is easy to understand, but not entirely correct, due to Vert.x asynchronous nature. What you'll get with it is probably a tiny span each time, unless your `message()` method is actually blocking.

More correct way would be:

```java
router.get("/home").handler((ctx) -> {
    Span span = tracer.buildSpan("my-operation")
      .withTag("example", "test")
      .start();
    ctx.response().endHandler((h)->{span.finish();})
    this.message(ctx);
    
});
```

This will invoke end of span when your response closes, and that's probably what you want.

To be clear, I don't have a running Vert.x instance with OpenTracing at the moment, so this is just an idea of how this should be implemented. Maybe you'll have to make some adjustments.

Comment: How am I supposed to track the event bus, When there are multiple consumers, Essentially making them the child spans. Any way to do that?

Comment: [link](https://www.codepile.net/pile/GYv7NPBl), I am passing the tracer and the span in the eventbus by a class to hold objects